# Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin not connecting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I am having problems with the Android Emulator Plugin in Jenkins. I am trying to start an emulator, but most of the times, it will just wait until the device is online, resulting in a timeout.

The errorcode can be seen here:

```
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
connected to localhost:6086
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe disconnect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline

... A LOT of repeating ...

$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s localhost:6086 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Jenkins\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb.exe connect localhost:6086
[android] Timed-out after waiting 720 seconds for emulator
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?